# Indexed Array Names in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, names

I have set of arrays named "list0 ........ through to list7" explicitly defined.
I want to make each of these arrays an element in an existing array (so I have a 2D array of these defined arrays)

how do I reference each 'list' array in a 'for' loop?

for example:

```
var matrix1 = new Array();

function makeMatrix1(){

    for(row=0; row<8; row++)
    {       

        matrix1[row] = list[row]//put each 'list' array into matrix1 as an element

    }
```

The above syntax does not work, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var matrix1 = [list0, list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, list7];
```

It's not a `for` loop, but it seems simple enough (perhaps simpler than a `for` loop) and gets the job done. The alternative, I think, would be to use an `eval` (which I personally try avoid at almost any cost).

```
var matrix1 = [];
for (row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
    matrix1.push(eval("list" + row));
}
```

Comment: yes, I can use different ways to make the 'matrix' array but what I want to be able to do as well is reference the 'list' arrays (in loops) by their index (0-->7).

Comment: @user3123418 - Once you construct `matrix1` (either as an explicit array or in a loop using `eval`), then `matrix1[i]` will evaluate to the array `list<i>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
   var myTwoDimArray = [listo,........,list7];
```

now print by

```
   alert(myTwoDimArray[0][0]);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

list0, list1, list2 etc is already numbered as an array structure. How about

```
list=new Array();
list[0]=["a","b","c"];
list[1]=["d","e"];
list[2]=["f","g","h","j"];
etc
```

then you already have your matrix structure. So as you are already defining rows explicitly you could do

```
matrix=new Array();
matrix[0]=["a","b","c"];
matrix[1]=["d","e"];
matrix[2]=["f","g","h","j"];
etc
```

matrix[1][1] would give "e"
matrix[2][3] would give "j"
etc

Of course you could just do

```
matrix=[
   ["a","b","c"],
   ["d","e"],
   ["f","g","h","j"],
.....
.....
and so on for each of the 8 rows

]
```

for same result